# How do I add a total as the last row in my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display a row, 'Total', that will do a sum of the Count column. The following code will have two columns, Environment and Count.

```
select 
case 
when env is null THEN 'Unknown' 
else env
end,
count(*) as Count
from env_table
group by env
order by env
/
```

Output I would like:

Windows   200

Linux     120

Total     320

As you can see above, what I would like to do is add a row called "Total" at the end that would essentially do a SUM(count(*)). What is the proper syntax to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be in SQL? You wouldn't normally mix this sort of thing into one query. If the data is rows of records, that's all it is, summary data is separate. As shown already, it *can* be done, I'm just not sure why you'd want to. There's no prize for reducing the number of queries executed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   IFNULL(env, 'Unknown'),
         COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     env_table
GROUP BY env WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY env
```

Comment: Rollup is exactly what I was looking for. Now the only problem is that the row is listed as "Unknown". How can I make this "Total"? Thanks for your help!

Comment: To select "Total" instead of null, you can use the `GROUPING` function as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Something like, `SELECT IF(GROUPING(env), 'Total', env), COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: @DarioSeidl: Indeed, that's a great addition in MySQL 8 that wasn't present in MySQL 5 when this answer was written :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT   IFNULL(env, 'Unknown'),
         COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM env_table
GROUP BY env
ORDER BY env
UNION ALL
SELECT   null,
         Count(*)
FROM env_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   COALESCE(env, 'Total') AS Description,
         COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     env_table
GROUP BY env WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY env
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT env, count 
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN env is null THEN 'Unknown' ELSE env END env,
               count(*) count
          FROM env_table
         GROUP BY env
      ORDER BY env)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' env,
       count(*) count
  FROM env_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works. In case, if any correction is needed, would love to hear my mistake.

```
select environment, count from table a
union all
(select "total" as environment, sum(count) from table b
group by 1)
```