# Issue with mathematical calculation inside SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having an issue with the total count of column records with the group by query. my data should be shown like:

```
Call Status               Call Results  Percentage
Answering Machine         1             5.6%
DO NOT CALL               9             50.0%
Good Transfer             4             22.2%
Looking for Information   4             22.2%
(blank)                                 0.0%
Total Calls               18
```

I am using the following query to do my work. But yet i am taking hardcore "18" because the problem occurs here that how i can take whole column count with group by.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT vs.status_name,vl.call_date,SUM(vl.called_count) as Total,SUM(vl.called_count)/18*100 as percentage from vl_users vu,".$vicidial_log_table." vl,vicidial_list vi,vicidial_statuses vs where vl.call_date >= '2014-01-17 00:00:00' and vl.call_date <= '2016-10-17 23:59:59' group by vs.status_name limit 100000") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

The number 18 above is the sum of the call result column.

Comment: It this MySQL **or** SQL Server? Please be more careful with your tags.

Comment: mysqli_query - MySQL

Comment: This is Mysql. i have removed sql server tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a total as the last row in my sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433885/how-do-i-add-a-total-as-the-last-row-in-my-sql)

Comment: But Actually @DavidG i don't have ny null value in the table.

Comment: `Group by Rollup` should help you

Comment: Are you sure you want to **cross join four tables**??? That seems highly unlikely. Where did you get the idea to use this ancient join syntax anyway? Use proper ANSI-1992 joins and decide what join types you want. Then update your request accordingly.

Comment: I am working on some system. Need to apply these mathematical operation there. I have an only issue with the group by clause with cll record column sum.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using a MySQL version that doesn't support explicit joins? Does such a version even exist? Of the early 1990s maybe? And you are cross joining on purpose? Are there one-row tables involved or how else does that work for you? Please post a proper query and explain how the tables are related (and whether they really only contain one row only). To change the query to determine the total itself will be very easy then. However, Richard Housham has already explained how to (though I'd prefer his solution #2).

Answer (score 1):

Right 3 ways of getting round this issue.

1. I would do the sum query first and then just add the sum into the percentage calc.
2. Might take a bit longer to calculate - in place of the 18 do a subquery to return the sum.
3. Don't use mysql to calculate the percentage. Instead use php to sum the array and then calc the percentage in each row while it's displaying.

1 - would be my recommendation.

Edit
Ok, given the complexity of the query it seems 3 is the answer.
So how to do it.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT vs.status_name,vl.call_date,SUM(vl.called_count) as Total from vl_users vu,".$vicidial_log_table." vl,vicidial_list vi,vicidial_statuses vs where vl.call_date >= '2014-01-17 00:00:00' and vl.call_date <= '2016-10-17 23:59:59' group by vs.status_name limit 100000") or die(mysqli_error($link));

$all_results = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

//might be a quicker way but
$sum = 0;
foreach($all_results as $s) {
    $sum  = $sum + $s['Total'];
}


//now to print
echo '<table><tr> <td>Call Status</td><td>Call Results</td><td>Percentage</td></tr>';

foreach($all_results as $row) {

   echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['status_name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['Total'].'</td>';

$percentage = 0;
if($sum > 0 && $row['Total'] > 0){
   $percentage = ($row['Total']/$sum)*100;
}
echo '<td>'.$percentage.'%</td>';


   echo '</tr>';




}

echo '</table>';
```

I just add that this is how I would do it, seems ok. I guess test and see.

Comment: Why? Calculate the sum of the rows first and then plug that in. Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: How i can access the sum of column sum inside the same query. It will cause Error.

Comment: @junkk rr: Like so: `select a, sum(b), (select sum(b) from t) as total from t group by a`.

Comment: The 3 solutions are correct and I would go 1 as well. Just throw the first query that Thorsten linked. Store the result in a PHP variable. Then when you prepare the scond query (your initial query), just change the 18 with that variable. Easy.

Comment: Why do you all prefer solution 1? Is MySQL's optimizer supposed to be so bad that it would run this non-correlated subquery multiple times? That is hard to imagine.

Comment: Well, have you loooked into his query ? He has 4 cross joins !!! Poor database. The first solution is not the most elegant but its the less intensive for the DB.

Comment: Ok, yeah 4 cross joins a group by. It's not great database design. In that case use option 3. Just one query. But then use php to get a total and calculate the percentage.

Comment: well in fact, I made a mistake while typing my first comment, the best approach for me is 3 and not 1, and that's what I described :)

Comment: But richard how i can take the full coumn sum in the 3rd step.

Comment: @junkk rr: It's not a step. It's three options that you have. If you go for #3 then simply loop through your array, add the sums, loop through your array again and do the calculation.